# Maven deployment for GCP App Engine on Gitlab

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I am using Maven to deploy a Java application on GitLab. I receive the following error. From what I understand it is using the the incorrect project and I don't understand which environment variable if they are using one or where they are getting that variable from. Every time I try to debug deploying with Maven on Gitlab I run into a new error is there a proper way to deploy on Gitlab?

This is my yml file

```
before_script:
    - echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-jessie main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
    - curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java
    - wget https://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz
    - tar xzvf apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz


test:1.1:
    image: python:2.7
    stage: deploy
    environment: Production
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - echo $DEPLOY_KEY_FILE_PRODUCTION > $CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
        - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - ./apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/mvn clean appengine:deploy
```

This is the error

```
Dec 17, 2018 8:08:54 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/gitlab-ci-155816]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  45.781 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-17T20:08:55Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project appengine-try-java: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```